# How can I read the step on which the test failed in an XML with the following structure using python or java?

Tags: java, python, xml, xml-parsing

How can I read the step on which the test failed in an XML with the following structure using python or java?

I've started parsing the XML with Python but I have to examin both java and Python options.

What I would like to read is :
"When Create empty DeactivateReason..........................................failed"

The number of failed steps can vary depending on the test-suite and the testcases.

How would you proceed?

```
<testcase classname="Extend" name="Check the total and process items for empty reasons" time="57.126683">
<failure message="org.springframework.retry.ExhaustedRetryException: Cannot locate recovery method...><![CDATA[
Given Data setup for extend.................................................passed
When Create empty DeactivateReason..........................................failed
Then Response should have 0 total and process items.........................skipped

StackTrace:
...
]]></failure>
</testcase>
</test-suite>
```

Comment: Use an XML parser library…

Comment: There are many libraries to parse XML in Java, depending on requirements. Choose one, locate the `failure` node and then parse its `CDATA` child as `String`.